# "out doing something" pattern

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

> He is **out drinking alcohol.**
>
> My mom is **out buying groceries.**

Does it mean: **someone is not at home for doing some work somewhere else?**

Is the sentence pattern **out doing something** valid and natural to native speakers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a pattern is common and well-understood.

Even the literal phrase of:

> My mom is out doing something.

works, meaning that your mom is currently not here but is doing something else (but you don't know/don't want to say what).